# How to perform union operation on an array field after group by aggregation on another field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, union, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the following documents in index `products`

```
{ "product_name": "prod-1", "meta": [ { "tag": "tag1", "score": "12" }, { "tag": "tag2", "score": "24" } ] }
{ "product_name": "prod-2", "meta": [ { "tag": "tag1", "score": "36" } ] }
{ "product_name": "prod-2", "meta": [ { "tag": "tag2", "score": "44" } ] }
{ "product_name": "prod-3", "meta": [ { "tag": "tag3", "score": "54" } ] }
```

I know how to group by `product_name` in es

```
POST /products/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
      "by_product": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "product_name"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

After grouping by `product_name`, I want a field called meta in each bucket which has a union of meta from all documents in that bucket like this

```
[
  {
    "key": "prod-1",
    "meta": [{ "tag": "tag1", "score": "12" }, { "tag": "tag2", "score": "24" }] 
  },
  {
    "key": "prod-2",
    "meta": [{ "tag": "tag1", "score": "36" }, { "tag": "tag2", "score": "44" }]
  },
  {
    "key": "prod-3",
    "meta": [ { "tag": "tag3", "score": "54" } ]
  }
]
```

How can I achive this in elaticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

> The best way to show your expected search result is to use [top hits
> aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation) using which you can add additional fields to terms
> aggregation

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_name.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_sales_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "meta.tag",
                "meta.score"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "by_product": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "prod-2",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "top_sales_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "64801386",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "meta": [
                      {
                        "score": "36",
                        "tag": "tag1"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "64801386",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "meta": [
                      {
                        "score": "44",
                        "tag": "tag2"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "prod-1",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_sales_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "64801386",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "meta": [
                      {
                        "score": "12",
                        "tag": "tag1"
                      },
                      {
                        "score": "24",
                        "tag": "tag2"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "prod-3",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_sales_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "64801386",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "4",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "meta": [
                      {
                        "score": "54",
                        "tag": "tag3"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: @sruthi it's been a long time. Did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)